# TRIGGER on DATABASE after insert SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, triggers, insert

I need to create a trigger on SQL database **DB1** that fires when one or more row has been inserted in table **T1**.

The problem is that the table where i need the trigger could be drop and re-created in a second time, so, if i write the trigger on table **T1** this would be dropped too.

what's the way to do that?

Comment: Then you need to manually recreate the trigger too. Thats the way to do it

Comment: there's not a way to make the trigger at DB node?

Comment: Why is the table getting dropped? That is unusual

Comment: A trigger is part of a table. Drop the table and the trigger is gone.

Comment: Why not `TRUNCATE` instead of `DROP`? That will retain the table schema and trigger.

Comment: cause it's a product of an update workflow in large structure of tables. i'm only trying to use SQL Server for update a column in T1 without using something external

Comment: Don't you have a (versioned controlled) script to (re)create the table? Include the trigger definition in that script. If you don't have such a script, it's time to think about a proper concept for your schema migrations

Answer (score 2):

You could create a DDL trigger that would recreate your trigger on table T1.

Maybe have the DDL trigger fire on `create table` statement, check if your T1 has been created, and, if so, recreate the trigger.